# How to resolve Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this code in Laravel-5.8 controller:

```
$goaltypes = GoalType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get();
foreach($goaltypes as $goaltype){
     $goaltypedetails = Goal::whereIn('goal_type_id', [$goaltype->id])->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->get();
}
```

I got this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

and it points at:

> foreach($goaltypes as $goaltype){

dd($goaltypes); gives me:

```
  #original: array:14 [▼
    "id" => 8
    "name" => "Employee Targets"
    "updated_by" => 2
    "created_at" => "2020-01-22 13:23:26"
    "updated_at" => "2020-02-25 14:12:30"
    "is_active" => 1
  ]
```

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: You code seems fine till now. The only reason you get this error is if `$goaltypes` is not an array.

Comment: What is the output of `dd(gettype($goaltypes));`

Comment: @sta - "object"

Comment: It should return an array. Anyway, you can make it as an array with toArray() method. `…->get()->toArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

laravel `get()` method return `Collection`  object , this collection has able iterator ,itterator object can  convert to array,already `Colllection`  has `toArray()`  method

> iterable object to array

```php
$array=iterator_to_array($object);
```

> or

```php
$array=$object->toArray();
```

> Also, the iterable object can be  iterate with foreach loop

```php
 foreach($object as $obj) 
 { 
    print $obj->foo;
 }
```

***Note***

**this code not logical, this code has `n+1` problem, and possibly cause a slowdown in provinces**

```php
$goaltypes = GoalType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get();
foreach($goaltypes as $goaltype){
     $goaltypedetails = Goal::whereIn('goal_type_id', [$goaltype->id])->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think that is bad practice in performance side to make model query inside the `foreach` loop
It will be good practice if you make one to many relationship between `GoalType` model and `GoalTypeDetail` then you can get `goaltypedetails` at any time you need.

The "invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error​ occurs when PHP’s built-in foreach() tries to iterate over a data structure that is not recognized as an array or object.